# nginx retaining IP of upstream server

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, aws-application-load-balancer

Within my AWS environment, I have an nginx server configured to point to an AWS application load balancer's DNS hostname within it's *http > upstream backends* configuration. All has been working just fine, but recently it would appear that the IP address of the AWS ALB as changed (although it's DNS hostname is immutable) causing my application to fail.

Digging through the nginx log files and checking `dig` results, it appears that nginx is retaining the IP address of the backend host and not attempting to resolve the IP address every time a request comes in. Once I restart the nginx service, everything starts working again.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    upstream backends {
        server internal-private-aws-alb-hostname.elb.amazonaws.com:443;
    }

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         my.servername.com;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem;
        ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://backends;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone experienced such behavior before and if so, aware of any configuration changes that could be made to make nginx more reliable in this manner? I wondered if there were caching configs that I should be focussing upon, but other than `ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;` configured in the *http* section, everything else is rather vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_pass` will not resolve DNS for every request, only looked up on start or configuration reload.

You can use a variable in `proxy_pass` to force resolve DNS, something like this:

```
resolver 127.0.0.1;
set $backend "foo.example.com";
proxy_pass http://$backend;
```

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832